# Unable write parser where the AST can be turned into Clojure code

Tags: clojure, ebnf, instaparse

Given the following example `"~a{b=1}&(a{b=1}|a{b=1})|a{b=1}|a{b=1}"` I have written the following parser using [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse)

```clj
((insta/parser
  "
S = (group | exp)+
group = '~'? <'('> exp+ <')'> op?
exp = '~'? path <'='> (v | r) <'}'> op?
path = (p <'{'>)* p
op = '|' | '&'
<p> = #'[a-z]'
v = #'[a-z0-9]'
r = <'\\''> #'[^\\']*' <'\\''>
")
 "~a{b=1}&(a{b=1}|a{b=1})|a{b=1}|a{b=1}")
```

Running the above output the following output

```
[:S
 [:exp "~" [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"] [:op "&"]]
 [:group
  [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"] [:op "|"]]
  [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"] [:op "|"]]
  [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]
  [:op "|"]]
 [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]]
```

However from this output I have a very hard time writing a transformation into Clojure expressions. To have a more straightforward transformation I would need something more like:

```
[:S
 [:op "|"
  [:op "&"
   [:exp "~" [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]
   [:group
    [:op "|"
     [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]
     [:op "|"
      [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]
      [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]]]]]
  [:exp [:path "a" "b"] [:v "1"]]]]
```

Given this structure it would be much easier to transform this in to Clojure.

How would your write a generic parser that can parse structures like the above and similar into an AST that can then be turned into Clojure code using a simple `insta/transfrom`?

Comment: I have used this for some inspiration but still im lost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216991/how-to-transform-instaparse-output-into-a-function-that-can-be-evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd follow the example from [Operator-precedence
parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser); this
will give you "single" `and`/`or` terms, but that should be easy to
trim/optimize away in your following steps.

```
S = expr
<expr> = and
and = or ( <'&'> or ) *
or= primary ( <'|'> primary ) *
<primary> = ( group | not | term )
<group> = <'('> expr <')'>
not = <'~'> term
term = #'a\\{b=[0-9]\\}'
```

E.g.

```clj
((insta/parser
   "
   S = expr
   <expr> = and
   and = or ( <'&'> or ) *
   or= primary ( <'|'> primary ) *
   <primary> = ( group | not | term )
   <group> = <'('> expr <')'>
   not = <'~'> term
   term = #'a\\{b=[0-9]\\}'
   ")
    "~a{b=1}&(a{b=2}|a{b=3})|a{b=4}|a{b=5}")
; →
; [:S
;  [:and
;    [:or [:not [:term "a{b=1}"]]]
;    [:or
;       [:and [:or [:term "a{b=2}"] [:term "a{b=3}"]]]
;       [:term "a{b=4}"]
;       [:term "a{b=5}"]]]]
```